# Runtime error in VBA for Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

So I am trying to write a module in Outlook that will parse the emails out of the emails I am being sent in the body of the message. I am getting a 'Runtime 424 Error" at this line of code

```
    For Each outlookMessage In outlookFolder.Items
```

It says that an object is required, I'm pretty sure the error is in reference to `For Each outlookMessage In outlookFolder.Items`

Can someone please help me out, I am not very good with VBA and I need some help.

Here is a portion of the code that I am talking about:

```
    ' Get all top level folders and find our target email folder....
 For iCtr = 1 To OutlookNameSpace.Folders.Item(1).Folders.Count
    ' handle case sensitivity as I can't type worth a crap
     If LCase(OutlookNameSpace.Folders.Item(1).Folders(iCtr).Name) = LCase(strTargetFolder) Then
     'found our target :)
        Set outlookFolder = OutlookNameSpace.Folders.Item(1).Folders(iCtr)
     Exit For  ' found it so lets move on
    End If
 Next
 'set up a header for the data dump, this is for CSV
 strEmailContents = "User,Remote,Forwarder,Encoding,timestamp" & vbCrLf

 'likely should have some error handling here, in case we have found no target folder
 'Set myFolderItem = outlookFolder.Items
 ' I have commenteted out some items to illustrate the call to Sue'strEmailContents Function
    For Each outlookMessage In outlookFolder.Items
          strMsgBody = outlookMessage.Body  ' assign message body to a Var
          ' then use Sue Moshers code to look for stuff in the body
          ' all of the following stuff in the quotes "" is specific to your needs

          strEmailContents = strEmailContents & ParseTextLinePair(strMsgBody, "E-mail:")
        '  strEmailContents = strEmailContents & "," & ParseTextLinePair(strMsgBody, "REMOTE_ADDR=")
         ' strEmailContents = strEmailContents & "," & ParseTextLinePair(strMsgBody, "HTTP_USER_AGENT=")
         ' strEmailContents = strEmailContents & "," & ParseTextLinePair(strMsgBody, "HTTP_VIA=")
       '   strEmailContents = strEmailContents & "," & ParseTextLinePair(strMsgBody, "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR=")
        '  strEmailContents = strEmailContents & "," & ParseTextLinePair(strMsgBody, "ENCODING=")
          'add the email message time stamp, just cause i want it
          strEmailContents = strEmailContents & "," & outlookMessage.ReceivedTime & vbCrLf
          'debug message comment it out for production
           'wscript.echo strEmailContents
     Next
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Does For Each **Item** In outlookFolder.Items works?

Comment: As follow up from your `For iCtr = 1..` loop you're seeking folder with specific name, and when this folder not found, your `outlookFolder` is Nothing. That's the reason of error. To handle an error you can add "if" statement: `If Not outlookFolder Is Nothing Then` just before `For Each outlookMessage In outlookFolder.Items` and `End If` just after `Next`

Comment: @simco What should i be putting in that if statement?

Comment: @user3109255, `If Not outlookFolder Is Nothing Then`

Comment: @simoco I mean what do i put in between the if and end if blocks...Like who should i do after If Not outlookFolder Is Nothing Then {Some code to perhaps set outlookFolder to something?} End If

Comment: @user3109255, it should be your `For Each outlookMessage In outlookFolder.Items ... Next` loop

Comment: @Simoco Oh okay, I just did that and I am getting the same error

Comment: If outlookfolder is nothing, then it wasn't set (found).  So it can't iterate over it.  Does this error occur when you give it a known folder name?

Comment: @JimmySmith yes, I set strTargetFolder = "FL1" earlier in the code... FL1 is the name of a folder in my account

Comment: @Alex No, it says Item an undefined variable

Comment: @Simoco Although now I am getting an error on'If Not outlookFolder Is Nothing Then'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion so far, the following code should work for you.  Maybe you are hitting a meeting invite or other nonmail item?

```
strTargetFolder = "inbox"
Dim outlookFolder As Object
Set OutlookNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
For iCtr = 1 To OutlookNamespace.Folders.Item(1).Folders.Count
    ' handle case sensitivity as I can't type worth a crap
     If LCase(OutlookNamespace.Folders.Item(1).Folders(iCtr).Name) = LCase(strTargetFolder) Then
     'found our target :)
        Set outlookFolder = OutlookNamespace.Folders.Item(1).Folders(iCtr)
     Exit For  ' found it so lets move on
    End If
 Next

strEmailContents = "User,Remote,Forwarder,Encoding,timestamp" & vbCrLf
if Not outlookFolder is Nothing then    
    For Each outlookMessage In outlookFolder.Items
        If TypeOf outlookMessage Is MailItem Then
             strMsgBody = outlookMessage.Body  ' assign message body to a Var
              strEmailContents = strEmailContents & ParseTextLinePair(strMsgBody, "E-mail:")
              strEmailContents = strEmailContents & "," & outlookMessage.ReceivedTime & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next
end if
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked!...I now have problems with other parts of my code; but you fixed my problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code never checks if outlookFolder is not null. What if the loop above cannot find it?

Secondly, how did you declare the outlookMessage variable? Did you declare it as MailItem (can't do that) or as a generic Object?

Comment: Im not sure what my error checking method should be. I have taken the advice of @simco but i dont know what i should put in my if statement. Also I am declaring outlookMessage as an object

Comment: "if Not outlookFolder is Nothing then" would do it.